# Indirect proof of universal statement

Tags: propositional-calculus

Can I prove $\neg R(x) \implies \neg R(y)$ by proving $\neg \neg R(y) \implies \neg \neg R(x)$?

Can I also prove that by proving $R(y) \implies R(x)$?

Comment: I'm asking about the technique. No other tags apply.

Comment: for most purposes, not not R(y) and R(y) are the same thing.

Comment: So if I go from not not R to just R in one line, would that be considered missing steps? (this is an intro course, and we're apparently marked strictly)

Comment: You should ask your instructors: we are not going to be able to guess :-)

Comment: Re terminology: your title says "Indirect proof of universal statement", but there's nothing "universal" going on here, no quantifiers in sight. "Indirect proof of implication" would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement $$\neg q \implies \neg p$$ is called the contrapositive of $$p \implies q.$$
Yes they are equivalent (at least in "classical logic" which it's 100% certain you're studying).
What @avid19 says in his answer is true too (proving one of these implications and inferring the other is called proof by contraposition).

Also ("classically"), both $$\neg \neg p \implies p$$ and $$p \implies \neg \neg p$$ are theorems, whatever $p$ might be.

We don't know what system you're working in, what the rules are, etc., so we can't say if you can go from $\neg\neg p$ to $p$ in one step or whether it will take more. You *can* prove the last two implications mentioned above, and then use *modus ponens*.

But... do you really need the double negations? If your goal is to prove $\neg R(x) \implies \neg R(y)$, it's surely easier to start with $R(y) \implies R(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, this is called proof by contraposition.